# Segments in solr index gets deleted after every restart

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have an issue with respect to increasing space on my Solr servers.

Whenever I see that the allocated space is almost full for a particular server, I perform a `service solr restart` and this clears up some space and things work normally from there for some time. Again this builds up and I get a space utilization 100% warning.

While debugging this, I found that for every Solr restart, for a couple of collections, there are some segments that gets deleted. Which means, for one segment, its corresponding .nvm, .fdx, .tvx, .si etc gets deleted.

`eg: This is one such segment that was deleted after the restart: _on0.nvm, _on0.si, _on0_Lucene50_0.dvm,_on0.fnm,_on0.fdx,_on0.tvx, _on0_Lucene50_0.tip, _on0.nvd, _on0_Lucene50_0.tim, _on0.fdt, _on0_Lucene50_0.dvd, _on0_Lucene50_0.doc, _on0_Lucene50_0.pos, _on0.tvd`

Can anyone please explain what probably would be happening behind the scenes for such a behavior? I have Solr Cloud with Solr version being 5.2.1 and lucene version 5.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

can you provide solrConfig.xml for those collections
Please Check for directoryFactory settings if set toRAMDirectoryFactory.
RAMDirectoryFactory is memory based, not
       persistent, and doesn't work with replication so it possible those segments are cleared